# While debugging in Eclipse the UI freezes completely. How can I find out what's going wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and am debugging Java Swing Events with Eclipse 4.3.

At a specific point a popup menu is shown by my application and that's the point where my UI freezes. Just the mouse pointer can be moved but nothing responds to it.

To end the freeze I go to TTY1, look up the latest java process and kill it.

I would like to find out what causes this error. Is it a systematical error or is there anything wrong? The reason I care is, because I would like to simply debug over that single point of interest :-)

The log files show no important entries (but I'm not totally sure about that). xsession-errors isn't updated and if I kill the process with -9 the situation continues to be akward: Key events work but the mouse is still not working correctly. Until I close Eclipse.

IMO this is a sign for something memory related. But top and the UI-tool show that there's enough memory left.

So what can I do to find the source of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to launch `eclipse` from teminal.

Comment: Yes, no output on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way to debug issues with any local Java app, if you haven't used it before, [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) really helps with runaway server processes. It launces as a gui application and attaches to any Java apps running in the same jvm. If Eclipse is locked up doing work this will at least let you know what methods is stuck on.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure how that would help.. Not only Eclipse but the whole OS-UI is freezing. So I couldn't even switch to VisualVM. OTH I already got a thread dump via kill -3.

Comment: If you're using Unity, have you tried a different desktop environment? That would at least point at either Unity or Compiz then you'd have a place to start looking with a tool like SystemTap. Dynamic tracing to root out an issue without getting a core dump from the process is the only way I know of to troubleshoot a locked process that won't actually emit any debug data.

Comment: Nope didn't try that. You mean using it parallel to Unity? Or to try if the problem occurs with the other desktop environment, too?

Comment: I mean trying it in the other environment to see if the behavior exists there as well. If it doesn't then it would likely be a bug in the Unity stack.